# Add multiple datagridview to form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am developing a software and i need different form of a DataGridView.

I created them and inserted them into an array with this method:

```
    private DataGridView[] cloneDataGridViews(int posCount, DataGridView dataGridView)
    {
        List<DataGridView> dataGridViewList = new List<DataGridView>();

        for(int i=0;i<posCount;i++)
        {
            DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView(); 
            dgv = dataGridView;
            dataGridViewList.Add(dgv);
        }

        return dataGridViewList.ToArray();
    }
```

And I am trying to show them with this code:

```
    void GridViewSelectorLoad(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.AutoScroll = true;
        int startY = 30;
        for(int i=0;i<dataGridViewArray.Length;i++)
        {
            int height = dataGridViewArray[i].Height;
            int posY = startY + 10 + i*height;

            Panel pnl = new Panel();
            pnl.Controls.Add(dataGridViewArray[i]);
            dataGridViewArray[i].Parent = pnl;
            pnl.Location = new Point(100,posY);
            pnl.Name = "pnl"+i.ToString();
            pnl.Height = dataGridViewArray[i].Height;
            pnl.Width = dataGridViewArray[i].Width;
            pnl.Parent = this;
            this.Controls.Add(pnl);
        }


    }
```

But it shows just one datagridview, how can I show all of them?
What is wrong with that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A control can only have one parent, but you're trying to set the same `DataGridView` as a child of multiple `Panel`s.

```
for(int i=0;i<posCount;i++)
{
    DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView(); 
    dgv = dataGridView;         // not creating a new instance of DataGridView
    dataGridViewList.Add(dgv);
}
```

Here's the relevant part of the `Controls.Add()` method that causes this behavior.

```
if (value.parent != null)
{
    value.parent.Controls.Remove(value); 
}
```

You've got a single instance of `DataGridView` that you add to each new `Panel`. Each time, it's `Parent` property is set to the latest `Panel`. Then when you try adding it to the next `Panel`, the code above removes it from the previous one.

If you create a new instance inside the loop, it works fine. You'll need to copy over those values from the existing `DataGridView` that you wish to have in each new `DataGridView` instance.

```
for(int i=0; i<posCount; i++)
{
    DataGridView dgv
        = new DataGridView
          {
              Name = dataGridView.Name,
              DataSource = dataGridView.DataSource,
              ...
          };

    dataGridViewList.Add(dgv);
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, i found out i am just referencing. Also i need to clone DataSources. If i dont, when i select a cell, that cell becomes selected in every datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

cloneDataGridViews is not cloning the datagrid, its adding the same instance multiple times:

```
dgv = dataGridView;
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been pointed out that all you are copying in your code is the same old reference to the same DGV into each slot of your list. Instead you will have to copy both the column structure and the values of all cells like this:

```
    public DataGridView cloneDataGridView(DataGridView oldDGV)
    {
        DataGridView newDGV = new DataGridView();

        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in oldDGV.Rows[0].Cells)
            newDGV.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn(cell));

        newDGV.Rows.Add(oldDGV.Rows.Count);

        for (int row = 0; row < oldDGV.Rows.Count; row++)
            for (int col = 0; col < oldDGV.Columns.Count; col++)
                newDGV[col, row].Value = oldDGV[col, row].Value;

        return newDGV;
    }
```

You could call it like this:

```
    for(int i=0;i<posCount;i++)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = cloneDataGridView(dataGridView); 
        dataGridViewList.Add(dgv);
    }
```

Note: This piece of code assumes that there is at least one row in the source DGV.